# Update Session Value using ajax Call in Express JS Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I need to update Session value on Ajax Calling But it update only on that function after reload page value is same as before.

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
          url:"trade_popup_visited",
          type:"post",
          data:{ user_id :user_id },
          success:function(response){
            if(response.status=="success"){
                window.location.href = redirect_url;
            }
          }
        });
```

**Server Side**

```
function trade_popup_visited(req, res){
   console.log("Home File ",req.session.userdata.is_trade_popup_visited); //Here it print 0 (Zero)
   req.session.userdata.is_trade_popup_visited = '1';
   console.log("Home File ",req.session.userdata.is_trade_popup_visited); //Here it print 1 (One)
}
```

After calling ajax on success response redirected on page where it Get **Zero** that means previous state.